# Formatting a line of String and Integers

Tags: java, format, string-formatting, decimalformat

For one of my assignments, I am required to format a line of Strings and Integers in a certain, spaced way. All of the Strings and Integers are data fields of an object which are accessed through get methods.

`getId` returns a six digit integer, `getName` returns a string with first and last name, `getAge` returns an integer, and `getGPA` returns a double up to 3 decimal places.

My instructor told me to use the DecimalFormat class and I've tried several  but I haven't been able to figure out how to because of the String, and I keep on getting an error saying `Cannot format given Object as a Number`.

I'm not sure how to incorporate the String as part of the DecimalFormat because all of the examples he gave us were to put 0s in front of a number or to format a number in currency format. How can I rewrite my DecimalFormat to match the sample output below?[image]

Here is the code that prints out the line, and the error.

```
System.out.println(format.format(temp.getID() + " " +temp.getName() + " " + temp.getAge() + " " + temp.getGPA()));
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Formatted Strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for some more ideas.  What does `getID` actually return? What is `format`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Use `printf`instead, here's a neat handy tuto: https://youtu.be/moQ3Kr8ouiU

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `format.format(temp.getID())...` with each variable do you want to format like this:

```
  System.out.println(format.format(temp.getID()) + " " +temp.getName() + " " + format.format(temp.getAge()) + " " + format.format(temp.getGPA()));
```

Not formating all variable together.

Comment: If there is a format statement after the `temp.getName()`, wouldn't the format start at different places for each line because each name ends in a different place? Would that require an additional string format for the `getName()`?